# Pull From Specific Branch using Smartgit

Tags: git, smartgit

I am using smartgit as my Git Client in Linux Mint. I used Source Tree in windows. I could pull from another branch in my branch in Source tree. How can I do this in Smartgit ?

Answer (score 4):

Right click on your local branch(from branches panel > local branches) on SmartGIT then click `set tracked branch`, and select the branch from which you want to do pull (Selected branch needs to be remote branch, which contains prefix like 'origin/')

Now all pull request's are pulled from that branch.

To revert this operation select `stop tracking`.

Answer (score 0):

First invoke **Remote|Pull** to get the latest commits of your branch, then use either **Branch|Rebase** or **Branch|Merge** to integrate the commits into your current branch.